# How do I make a base command then add-ons in discord? I am using python

Tags: python, discord

Ok, if that didnt make any sense here's what i'm trying to say. I'm creating a bot that has a small database for my discord server so that people can view the information of a song by using !songinfo{name of song}. So if i wanted to find info for the song 'cool beans', i would type !songinfo cool beans. However, you cant put spaces in commands so how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this question I am assuming that you are using discord.py

Your function most likely looks something like this

```
@client.command()
async def songinfo(ctx, song_name):
    ...Your Code...
```

With this code, if I entered the following into Discord

```
!songinfo example song
```

Then "song_name" would be equal to "example."

But if I just change the parameters of the function a little by adding a '*' parameter before 'song_name' like this

```
@client.command()
    async def songinfo(ctx, *, song_name):
        ...Your Code...
```

now "song_name" would be equal to "example song" rather than just "example"